# Magento products issue

Tags: magento

I am having trouble organising my products in Magento and wondered if anyone could help.
I want to sell a mobile phone which has colour options with dropdown box, and SIM card options with drop down box, plus a single checkbox option for a 'set-up your phone' package.  I have tried crating a configurable product but that didn't work as I would need to create attributes for every combination of colour and sim card together - technically it can be done, but we won't sell like this as it would tie all my stock together. (ie black mobile phone with Orange SIM card/Black Mobile phone with )2 sim card/White Mobile pHone with Orange Simcard etc etc).

I also tried to add some custom options for the options, which did seem to work but I can't track stock via this method.

I thought that creating a configurable product which could be associated with a bundled products might be a solution, but Magento doesn't allow this.

Any opinions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bundled products are most likely the way to go. You don't need to create a configured product to add to the bundle, just add all the simple product options into each 'bundle item'. It's difficult to explain in words.

You might have to try a few things out but I think you should create simple products for the phone in each colour eg phone-black, phone-white, phone-gold and simple products for each SIM card or SIM card combination. And create a simple product for 'set up your phone package'.

Then create a new bundle product and in '`Bundle items`' click '`Add new option`' three times. One for the choice of phone, one for the choice of SIM and one for the set-up package. For each one, eg for the phone, give it a `Default title` like 'Mobile Phone', `Input Type` Dropdown, `Is required` = yes, `Position` = 1, and then click '`Add Selection`'.

Now you can filter and add all the simple phone products.

Repeat that process for the other two bundle items: all the SIMS and the set-up package (but for the set-up package set `Is required` = no).

Press `Save` and you should be all set. You might create different bundle products for different phone manufacturers eg Nokia, Samsung, LG.

Have faith in Magento. It is awkward to use but very capable.

(Also, I hope you don't mind me saying, stackoverflow is mostly for coding problems rather than how to use Magento type questions so maybe an editor will advise a better place to ask this or correct me if I am wrong to point that out).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Malachy.  I created the bundled product and that did seem to work!  I appreciate stackoverflow is more for coding questions but as I found some question had already been asked I thought it might be worth a try.  You have got back to me much quicker than anyone ever has on the official Magento forum.  I really appreciate your help!